# AS3 - Read all values from properties file that match certain key pattern

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, properties, flex4

I've got a properties file with two distinct key-value pair patters like the following;

1. name.name.name.key = value
2. name.name.fullname.key = value

Accessing them one by one is fine if the key is known.
What I need now, though, is to access ALL values from say name.name.name without knowing the keys (integers to be exact). The values then have to be added to an ArrayList to be displayed in a List.

The keys are completely random, so I don't know the range beforehand (I can't and don't want to hardcode the range of range of keys for each single properties file), so simply looping through a previously defined range isn't what I need here. Also, the keys are not successive.

How can I do this with AS3?

Just for clarification as this seems to be a little confusing;
I do not want to parse the properties file. I rather want to solve this using the methods AS and Flex already provide.
The ResourceBundle class already has a method that outputs the content of the specified bundle. However, it contains all values. What I need is just a subset of values that match a given key pattern.

Edit:
To make this easier, I can drop the key pattern matching and create a new resource file with a distinct pattern. Now I only need to get all key-value pairs (I need both the integers from the keys and the value) from that resource.

Comment: Hard to tell exactly what you need here. Are you trying to make a string parsing method that will result in a Dictionary where each key has a list of values? Or does each key have one value?

Comment: I would like to avoid parsing the whole properties file as it is quite extensive and parsing it in real time would take too much time. I figure the ResourceManager is the way to go to solve this problem as it is made to get key-value pairs from given properties files. Each key does in fact have only one value. Getting a Dict from the properties file where the keys match a certain pattern would indeed be ideal. That's pretty much exactly what I'm after, but unfortunately the ResourceManager doesn't seem to provide such a method, or does it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple example with string parsing:

```
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.events.Event;

var l:URLLoader = new URLLoader(new URLRequest("inp.txt"));
l.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);


function onComplete(e:Event):void
{
    var data:String = e.target.data;
        //remove whitespace
    data = data.replace(' ','');
        //split data string by lines
    var pairs:Array = data.split("\r\n");
        //our name search pattern
    var pattern:RegExp = /name\.name\.name/;
        //array to store extracted values
    var values:Array = [];
    for each (var s:String in pairs) {
        if (pattern.test(s)) {
            //we've got a match, let's extract value
            var value:String = s.split("=")[1];
            values.push(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cheers mate, unfortunately not what I'm looking for. I already have the properties file with key-value pairs and to make it easier, I can also drop the key pattern and simply put those pairs that fit this pattern in a separate resource, leaving me with the task to get all key-value pairs from the resource with a single call.

Comment: Well, since no one seems to know how to solve this with the ResourceManager, I'll stick to string parsing. However, your String.split in the loop only returns the value of the first line, not the first value of the split value, which seems odd as it should work.

Comment: You can solve it with the ResourceManager by subclassing ResourceBundle and creating a method which extract all the keys and values based on pattern you provide. Or do you need actual code? Regarding the string parsing solution, I've just tested it once again and I get all the values that match the pattern. Can you share concrete implementation of my code just to be sure?

Comment: Subclassing the ResourceBundle sounds like a good idea. I'm fine without code, basically looking for ideas here to solve this issue. As for the string parsing, I basically took your code as is without the RegEx since I copied the pairs with that very pattern in a different file. I've added an answer (not sure where to put the code instead) with the code.

Answer (score 0):

The adapted String formatting method provided by package;

```
function onComplete(e:Event):void
{           
    var data:String = e.target.data;
    var pairs:Array = data.split("\r\n");

    var values:Array = [];
    for each (var s:String in pairs) {    
        var value:String = s.split("=")[1];
        values.push(value);

    }
    trace(values);

}
```

Not sure why, but the trace gives me the value of the first pair plus the key of the second pair.
No idea why.

I actually though about adding the keys and values in a Dictionary, around the lines of this;

```
_dict[arr[0].substr(0, arr[0].length)] = arr[1];
```

Comment: Have you tried tracing `pairs`? I suspect that something is wrong with the splitting. The "\r\n" part might be suitable for my environment, but might be different for mac/linux.

Comment: pairs as well as s (the actual line) is perfectly fine, that's why I'm wondering the split doesn't work properly. Edit: Wait, actually it isn't! I get a split between the first line and the rest! Thanks for the heads up! Working on it!

Comment: Problem solved, \n works as expected. I'll set your answer to accepted since I'll basically to the same in the subclassed ResourceManager class. Thanks for your help mate!